# A better way to say "suddenly remember."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

You suddenly remember something you should have done, you meant to do, or that changes your plan. Is there a phrase or word to use instead of "suddenly remember"? I suddenly remember things so often that it makes bad fiction story-telling.

Comment: You can remember all-of-sudden, it can all come rushing back to you, it can just hit you. But as written the question asks for a "better way" which makes it Primarily Opinion-based and off-topic.

Comment: Please describe how the word will be used and/or provide a sample sentence.

Comment: It just came to me; I just recalled; Oh, I need to ...

Comment: For example, I wrote: On the way, I missed a turn because we were so engaged in pleasant conversation. I stopped when I remembered I hadn't removed the signs from the windows. As I returned to my seat after taking care of that, I remembered the [trash] in my coat pocket.

Comment: @Iliketowalk Since your example doesn't include 'suddenly remember', can't you just miss out the 'suddenly' more often? I do think you are right to consider alternatives, one of my big bugbears in fiction is the frequency with which people do things suddenly when it adds nothing. Your context tells you that it wasn't something remembered 'gradually' or 'slowly'. Perhaps consider less 'remembering' and more 'realising', thinking about' or having things 'occur to you' or 'come to mind'.

Comment: Lots and none at all…

Even if there was something special about *suddenly remembering* there isn't a particular phrase that expresses it. Several, possibly dozens of phrases but nothing special.

Comment: @RobertGoodwin What about when it's a proper shock:  *Just when the plane set in motion, I suddenly remembered I left my wallet by the officer.*

Answer (score 1):

occur to someone ([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/occur+to))

> [for an idea or thought] to come into someone's mind. *It occurred to me that you might be hungry after your long journey. Would it ever occur to you that I want to be left alone?*